# How to make a 60fps navigation flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

Recently, I have used flutters navigation.
It works good but it lags even on my physical device.
 I was thinking to change it to pageview but than I have second thoughts so I decided to use its navigation.
How can I make smooth navigation?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were probably using the debug mode on your device. Connect your device and run the command `flutter run --release`to deploy the app in release mode to your device, it shouldn't lag like that - if it does you might have some work running on your UI thread in an awkward way. 
It's not recommended to use pageview for the entire app navigation as those views will be kept in memory.

Comment: thank you so much, I was scared that I need to rewrite my app, even started reading articles about flutter performance.

Answer (score 1):

To check the fps or the performance of your flutter app, run your app in profile mode instead of release mode. You will be able to see the rendering time of your frames in profile mode. For more info, visit https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/ui-performance.